# exclude stdout based on an array of words

Tags: arrays, shell, awk, sed, grep

## Question:

Is it possible to exclude some of a commands output its output based on an array of words?**

### Why?

On Ubuntu/Debian there are two ways to list all available pkgs:

1. `apt list` (show all available pkgs, installed pkgs too)
2. `apt-cache search .` (show all available pkgs, installed pkgs too)

Difference is, the first command, you can exclude all installed pkgs using `grep -v`, problem is unlike the first, the second command you cannot exclude these as the word "installed" isnt present. Problem with the first command is it doesnt show the pkg description, so I want to use `apt-cache search .` but excluding all installed pkgs.

```sh
# List all of my installed pkgs,
# Get just the pkg's name,
# Swap newlines for spaces,
# Save this list as an array for exclusion.

INSTALLED=("$(apt list --installed 2> /dev/null | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | tr '\r\n' ' ')")
```

I then tried:

```sh
apt-cache search . | grep -v "${INSTALLED[@]}"
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work as I still see my installed pkgs too so I'm guessing its excluding the first pkg in the array and not the rest.

Again thank you in advance!

Comment: If you [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (i.e. the output of the various commands you mention that provide the various lists you want to compare) and expected output of the tool you want to write to operate on that input then we can help you.

Comment: better now? sorry Im new and dont understand the downvote, but I edited the question to be short & sweet now.

Comment: No, you list some commands and say you want a tool that does something with the output of those commands. You need to provide examples of the output of those commands (input to the tool you want to write) and the final output from that tool you want to write given that input. Hope that makes sense, if not see [ask].

Comment: Right now it's like you're saying you want to compare the output of "fluffy" against the output of "bunny" and asking for help to do so - OK, show us what that output looks like and what you want done with it. Give us a [mcve] with concrete input and output that we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A installed                            # an associative array to memorize the "installed" command names

while IFS=/ read -r cmd others; do              # split the line on "/" and assign the variable "cmd" to the 1st field
    (( installed[$cmd]++ ))                     # increment the array value associated with the "$cmd"
done < <(apt list --installed 2> /dev/null)     # excecute the `apt` command and feed the output to the `while` loop

while IFS= read -r line; do                     # read the whole line "as is" because it includes a package description
    read -r cmd others <<< "$line"              # split the line on the whitespace and assign the variable "cmd" to the 1st field
    [[ -z ${installed[$cmd]} ]] && echo "$line" # if the array value is not defined, the cmd is not installed, then print the line
done < <(apt-cache search .)                    # excecute the `apt-cache` command to feed the output to the `while` loop
```

- The associative array `installed` is used to check if the command is
  installed.
- The 1st `while` loop scans over the installed list of the command and
  store the command names in the associative array `installed`.
- The 2nd `while` loop scans over the available command list and if the
  command is not found in the associative array, then print it.

BTW your trial code starts with `#!/bin/sh` which is run with `sh`, not `bash`.
Please make sure it looks like `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you so much! just accepted this answer! unfortunately im -1 for asking it though :'(

Comment: Thank you for the feedback with courtesy. I've compensated the unreasonable -1.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but you just want to get the list of packages which are not installed, right?

If so, you can just do this -

```
apt list --installed=false | grep -v '\[installed'
```

Comment: 1) As stated, I want to use `apt-cache search .` as it includes pkg descriptions. 2) if using `--installed=false` then `grep -v \[installed` wouldnt be needed (installed arent listed anyway).